# Post content exceeds limit on line 0

Tags: php, post, upload

These are my settings:

```
        ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
        ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');
        ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2000M');
```

Somehow it fails to upload a total of 17 MB, and i get this error:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 17785546 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

so it appears as if my ini_set is not really functioning..

Comment: Have you edited the `php.ini` correctly ?

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting or do you have a VPS/local/dedicated server of your own?

Comment: I work local :) And yes, i have tried to edit the php.ini, The only effect this seemed to have, is that it suddenly couldn't find my config.php anymore..

Comment: Solved my problem.. appears that it makes a difference of where i make the changes in the php.ini. I made the changes in the actual lines, that didn't work. but when you put all changes on the last lines it works perfectly.. thanks for thinking along!